# Play Framework + Spring: Injecting URL from application.conf

Tags: java, spring, playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm using Spring 4.1.x with Play 2.3.x and I'm trying to inject a property value from Play's `application.conf` file.

I can access properties thanks to this:

`@PropertySource("classpath:application.conf")`

```
@Bean
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
    return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
}
```

I have a URL value in my `application.conf`:

`photo.url="https://our-photo-storage.net"`

Note the **quotes**. If I remove them, Play will throw `com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$Parse`.

I am injecting property value like this:

```
@Autowired
public PhotoToUrlMapper(@Value("${photo.url}") url) {
    // trim quotes :-/
}
```

Spring will inject the value **with the quotes**. I can obviously just trim them, but I'd like to be able to inject the url without the quotes.

Notes:

- I could probably create a separate `.properties` file, but I'd like to avoid that (more configuration)
- I could probably use horrible static Play's `Play.current.configuration.getString("photo.url")`, but I actually like to write unit tests ...

Is there a reasonable workaround for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the only way to so is to use the properties file, i don't think that's too much configuration to do, since it provides you with a better readability for your code. quoted a sample of the code you need to include your properties file

```
<bean id="placeholderProperties"                
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:/url.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true" />
        <property name="order" value="1" />
    </bean>
```